# Pre Merge Commit Server Hook in Self Hosted Gilab CE

Tags: git, git-merge, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

Before briefing my issue, here is he snap of my environment -

SVN - Gitlab Self Hosted Community Edition
Version - 15.3

So in the above gitlab server I am trying to setup a **Pre-Merge-Commit** server hook by placing script in custom hook folder in specified location, but when I am initiating a Merge Request for merge, seems script is not executing and it's always merging the code.

In one of the response on ChaGPT, it saying the Gitlab CE does not support pre-merge-commit server hook. Is it true ?

If not can someone help me with the correct approach?